# Cosa vuol dire "pagare" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Leggendo le [notizie su RaiNews](http://www.rainews.it/dl/rainews/articoli/Coronavirus-terza-vittima-a-Crema-Conte-No-al-panico-seguire-le-indicazioni-delle-autorita-c544be17-1c34-45d5-967c-4e32425095f9.html), mi sono imbattuta in questa frase, pronunciata da Conte, che non ho capito (**grassetto mio**):

> La linea della massima precauzione **ha pagato**, anche se sembrerebbe di no.

Fa riferimento alle misure di contenzione presse all'inizio dell'epidemia della malattia COVID-19 in Italia.

Quello che difficolta la mia comprensione è l'uso che se ne fa del verbo "pagare": l'ho cercato in alcuni dizionari (Treccani e GDLI), ma non riesco a vedere a quale accezione possa corrispondere. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Il senso di "valere la pena" è di uso piuttosto recente e, a mio modesto avviso, coniato sul "pay off" inglese.

Comment: Adesso che ho capito il significato, posso dire che si tratta di un uso figurato di "pagare" peculiare in comparazione con gli usi figurati di "pagar" in castigliano o in catalano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

È un'espressione idiomatica per significare "è stata utile, ha prodotto risultati".
Vedi, per esempio, sul [dizionario Garzanti](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=pagare) il significato 5:

> portare utilità, vantaggio: il delitto non paga

Comment: Ah! Va bene: corrisponde all'accezione numero 23 del [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI12/00000368.jpg). Questo dizionario è fantastico e, ultimamente, l'ho sto usando molto. Ma di solito ci sono tantissime accezioni che a volte mi perdo.

Comment: Sul GDLI è marcato come neologismo, quindi deve essere un uso relativamente recente.

Comment: @Charo: curiosa, questa cosa del neologismo. Ma se lo dice il GDLI allora dev'essere proprio così.

Answer (score 2):

In questo contesto ha pagato significa che il sacrificio, l'attenzione, le misure straordinarie adottate che sono costate fatica, impegno, etc., hanno dato il risultato sperato, hanno ripagato gli sforzi.

L'accezione di [pagare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pagare/) di Treccani che più si avvicina è la seguente:

> 2. fig. Ricompensare, corrispondere, rendere il contraccambio (più com., in questo senso, ripagare)

Comment: Avevo visto questa accezione prima di porre la domanda. Tuttavia mi era sembrato che non so corrispondesse con l'uso di "pagare" della frase della domanda perché anche in castigliano e in catalano usiamo molto "pagar" con questo stesso senso (cercando su Google Libri, [questa](https://books.google.es/books?id=uNiACQAAQBAJ&pg=PT8&lpg=PT8&dq=%22me+lo+paga+con%22&source=bl&ots=a5PLlIkgIp&sig=ACfU3U3_fpjliSJjnCxVCyGeah4aoCPCtA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXwrPEje3nAhUmz4UKHUrKB1kQ6AEwA3oECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22me%20lo%20paga%20con%22&f=false) è l'occorrenza che mi è apparsa in primo luogo), ma...

Comment: ...non è possibile tradurre questa frase in spagnolo o in catalano usando il verbo "pagar".